# Redirect в GitHub

Tags: github, redirect, github-pages

Залил самый простенький сайт на гитхаб, чистый html.
Подскажите как настроить редирект, когда есть page1, на странице index на нее стоит ссылка, но теперь страницы page1 нет, вместо нее page3 и нужно решить именно редиректом, а не изменением ссылки на странице index

Answer (score 1):

GH простой как бревно и никаких редиректов там нет.

Стандартный способ использовать [meta refresh](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta).

Создайте страницу `page1` с примерно таким содержимым:

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/page3">
<a href="/page3">страница переехала</a>
```

вместо `/page3` надо поставить нужную ссылку.